# Finding K-Shortest Path in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Facing Problem in Finding Weighted K-shortest path in neo4j among 2M+ nodes,2M+ relationships

Query Tried :

```
MATCH p = (s:Test)-[:to*1..5]->(e:Test)
WHERE s.name = 'ABC'
RETURN *,
  relationships(p),
  sum(reduce(sum=0,x in relationships(p) |sum+x.count)) as tt
ORDER BY tt desc limit 4
```

Above query is taking too much time, the most time-consuming operation is calculating cost sum. if there is any other approach that can give me the result in less time. let me know

Comment: The `sum()` function does not seem to be necessary, since your `reduce` is already summing. The `sum()` function is an [aggregating function](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/3.4/cypher/functions/aggregating/), and  so the other returned values ("*, relationships(p)") are acting as `grouping keys`, so it seems the `sum()` function would always be summing a single value -- which is a waste of time.

Comment: How many paths are there for that particular pattern (if you return `count(*)` in place of your RETURN)?

Comment: @cybersam that i have done but still its taking too much time

Comment: @InverseFalcon it tried its giving 1 million i think its taking all nodes

Comment: I did not actually expect removing `sum()` to solve your main issue, but it needed to be pointed out, and was at least slowing you down to some extent.

Comment: Have you taken a look at [Yen’s K-shortest paths algorithm](https://neo4j.com/docs/graph-algorithms/current/algorithms/yen-s-k-shortest-path/), which is supported by the neo4j Graph Algorithms plugin?

Comment: @cybersam Usually you need to know your start and end node ahead of time. In this case we only know the start node. If we tried this it would generate a cross product of the start node with all :Test nodes and execute the algorithm for each pairing.

Comment: @cybersam Yes Yen's  K-shortest path i tried but its was taking cross product that was also making it slow